# How can I parse an URL's HTML and insert data to a Google Sheet using Google Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm completely new to Google Apps Script and JavaScript.

I just wanted to:

1. Read **column A** and do an URL request.
2. Parse the URL's HTML to get the `title` and `num count`.
3. Write the `title` into **column B** and the `num count` into **column C**.

**Here's my code:**

```js
function getHtml()
{
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    var url_range = sheet.getRange('A1:A').getValue();
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
    var content = response.getContentText("UTF-8"); 

    var title = new Array();
    var num_count = new Array();

    for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
        title = content.match(/<title>(.*?)<\/title>/);
        num_count = content.match(/<span class="num_count">(.*?)<\/span>/);
    }

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("sheet1");

    for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
        sheet1.getRange(i,2).setValue(title[i]);
        sheet1.getRange(i,3).setValue(num_count[i]);
    }
}
```

But I only get the below result:

[image]

Please tell me what I should improve.

Comment: On line 4 you are declaring `url_range` but on line 5 you are using `url`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your scraping works I think this is pretty close to what you require.

```
function getHtml()
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range=sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(),3);                 
  var data=range.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(data[i][0]);
    var content = response.getContentText("UTF-8"); 
    data[i][1]=content.match(/<title>(.*?)<\/title>/);
    data[i][2]=content.match(/<span class="num_count">(.*?)<\/span>/);
  }
  rg.setValues(data);
}
```

Comment: Could i have few questions more? **1.error handling** i wand to handle type Error like Column A is not URL(text type, unreadable url or api etc...). in this case what could i add in my code?  **2. slice valule** when i got Column B value, it contains html tag. (ex. **<strong class="tit_info">**(Only value that i wanted)**</strong>**). How could i slice out those html tag and get value? i was tryng to data[i][0].slice(15, -8). but it does not work.

Comment: 1. Maybe a regex. 2. I use slice and indexOf together a lot. Test in console until you find.